# How to programatically invite users for Google Hangout on Air?

Tags: java, rest, google-hangouts

I want to use a registration platform like Eventbrite/Townscript to get the user emails who are interested in attending my Google Hangout on Air. Now I want to programatically invite those User Emails for Hangout. How to do that?

I also had a look at [Google Hangout API Page](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api) but couldn't figure out the way. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use something like this in your website which will create the hangout button.
Try to modify the invites based on the web framework you use.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    <title>Hangout button demo: Inviting people</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : '1234', invite_type : 'PROFILE' },
                  { id : 'foo@example.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
</body>
</html>
```